# Access denied 'homestead'@'localhost' when running a Laravel Command

Tags: laravel

I'm having some trouble getting Laravel to connect to my database, when using a custom Artisan command.

I can post my command but I'll skip to my db settings as I suspect that is what is wrong. In `start.php` I have:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('homestead'),

));
```

and then I have no local/database.php files in my config. Instead I have a `.env.local.php` which works great for everything except this. All database settings are set as `'DB_NAME => getenv('DB_NAME');` etc.

When I run `php artisan custom:command` I get the following:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: select * from `users` where `paused_until` = 3)
```

Then if I run

```
php artisan fdb:reactivate-paused --env=local
```

I seem to get much closer but still get:

```
Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is it that Laravel doesn't know to use the .env.local.php file when I am running commands in the terminal? All my migrate and db:seed queries seem to work fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try  renaming `.env.local.php` to `.env.local` or just `.env`

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Were you trying to run the command from within your local machine, or from the VM (homestead)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at it again this morning, I must have been 100% burnt out. I was running the command from my Local Machine, not the Homestead VM.